iCloud Container Syncing to different devices during development? Objective C IOS
I am not understanding how adding iCloud Document Container/Entitlement to your app is supposed to work during development.
I have everything setup in my development and adhoc provision.  i seem to have everything showing in entitlements.  i receieve my ubiquityIdentityToken.  i receive my URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier path.  i can upload and download on a test ipad or test iphone or simulator without any issues and the documents go to the correct mobile documents/icloud folder local on the test device.
the problem is if i upload a document on my test ipad device.  then i go to my test iphone device, there is no sync.  even if i wait 24 hours.  isnt the purpose of using icloud documents so you can see the document across different devices using the same icloud container?
can someone explain why everything works but it doesnt seem to be actually using "the cloud".  just seems to be local which doesnt help me accomplish the goal of sharing documents in the same application across devices.
thanks in advance!!
